# Google Cloud Storage Asking For Login While Downloading Public File

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I upload image in bucket of Google Cloud Storage via external API. I also assigned all access rights. I shared file download link with my friends which is similar to

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/buketName/fileName.extension
```

But the problem is that sometimes it asks for Google authentication login and sometimes not.

Bucket files permission is given to all users, still sometimes it ask for login. Don't know why?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To reach public files without being logged in Google account you should use a link like this:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME]
```

In order to reach files with link that you provided, even if they are public, you have to be signed in with your Google account.

Comment: any quota restrictions on this?